# How to find distance between two points using google maps geometry library?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I have attached the library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com`/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
```

I have place A, with Latitude 30.694491 and longitude 76.665095
and place B with Latitude 30.7141289 and longitude 76.709398

```
<script>
    computeDistanceBetween(from:LatLng, to:LatLng, radius?:number);
</script>
```

i dont know how to add lat and long to above function???
i want the distance between 2 places!!!!

and also is it possible to find displacement between them????

Comment: If you are looking for this
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_responses ...

Comment: please fix your title and the formatting of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(a,b)` to find distance between two points... [read about computeDistanceBetween](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance)

It's in meters

```js
var a = new google.maps.LatLng(30.694491, 76.665095);
var b = new google.maps.LatLng(30.7141289, 76.709398);
console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(a,b));
alert(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(a,b));
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create LatLng Objects.

```
var _aCord = new google.maps.LatLng(30.694491, 30.694491);
var _bCord = new google.maps.LatLng(30.7141289, 76.709398);

computeDistanceBetween(_aCord, _bCord);
```

Comment: i tryed var _aCord = new google.maps.LatLng(30.694491, 30.694491);
var _bCord = new google.maps.LatLng(30.7141289, 76.709398);

var t=computeDistanceBetween(_aCord, _bCord);

but its nt wrking

alert(t);

Comment: What's the output? Do you have any errors in the console? Maybe try: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(_aCord, _bCord);

Comment: yea console has following errors

"Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys" util.js:220:12
"Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required"

Comment: You need to get an API Key, see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key